# Strange result from a script

Tags: sql-server-2014

Hope you can enlighten me.

I'm running this script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DB_Name(Database_id) AS 'DatabaseName',
    V.OBJECT_ID AS ObjectId,
    Object_Name(V.Object_id) AS ObjectName,
    V.Index_ID AS IndexId,
    U.name as IndexName,
    V.Index_Type_Desc AS IndexDescription,
    V.avg_record_size_in_bytes,
    V.record_count,
    STATS_DATE(V.object_id, V.index_id) AS 'lastupdated',
    CONVERT([varchar](512), round(Avg_Fragmentation_In_Percent, 3)) AS 'AvgFragmentationInPercent'
FROM 
    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'detailed') V
JOIN 
    sys.indexes U ON V.object_id = U.object_id AND V.index_id = U.index_id
WHERE 
    V.OBJECT_ID IS NOT NULL
    AND U.name = 'Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA_AK'
ORDER BY 
    IndexName
```

I get a result I didn't expect:

```
DatabaseName    ObjectId    ObjectName  IndexId IndexName   IndexDescription    avg_record_size_in_bytes    record_count    lastupdated AvgFragmentationInPercent
CM_PBN  101575400   Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA 3   Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA_AK  NONCLUSTERED INDEX  96,899  1966    2018-06-07 16:54:04.610 100
CM_PBN  101575400   Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA 3   Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA_AK  NONCLUSTERED INDEX  98,536  41  2018-06-07 16:54:04.610 0
CM_PBN  101575400   Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA 3   Add_Remove_Programs_64_DATA_AK  NONCLUSTERED INDEX  104,797 112316  2018-06-07 16:54:04.610 3.561
```

As you can see the result contains a single index but shows up three times. I have no idea why. So I hope I am just blind not seeing the obvious reason. Thank you very much for your efforts.

Comment: Have you tried including `index_level` in your select list to see what is going on? Since you are using the `detailed` mode, I think `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` is returning a separate row for root, intermediate, and leaf levels as per this [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Aah thank you very much EdmCoff. Yes, I missed that index_level. The above script is part of a maintenance script taking care for fragmentation and statistics. Those other parts of course use index_level as parameter. Thank you again. :)